# Whats the benefit of allowing multiple null keys in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Just for experimenting, I added multiple `null` keys in a `Hashmap` instance. And it didn't complain. What's the benefit of doing that?

The code is,

```
Map hmap = new HashMap();
hmap.put("sushil","sushil11" );
hmap.put(null,null);
hmap.put(null,"king");
hmap.put(null,"nagasaki");
hmap.put(null,null);
```

How many keys are there in the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to get switch:case:default behavior.

Example:

Problem Definition: Coffee shop in CS Department building. They provide coffee to CS Student for $1.00, to IT department students $1.25 and others for $1.50.

Then Map will be:

Key -> Value

IT  -> 1.25

CS  -> 1.00

null -> 1.50

> if(map.containsKey(dept))
>
> price =  map.get(dept);
>
> else
>
> price = map.get(null);

P.S. - I am not "Department-ist" if that's a word. :)

Answer (score 12):

I would guess you haven't added multiple `null`-keys. You just overwrote the same `null`key multiple times.

Comment: Could u please tell me what adding null as a key would benifit me.

Comment: I think @Babban Shikaari has an example in his answer. I don't can come up on my own for now, but I prefer having the option of using the null-key instead of needing it but beeing unable to use it :P

Answer (score 7):

A normal hashmap will have unique keys, so you're overwriting the entry for the null key repeatedly. You won't have multiple identical keys (for this you need a MultiMap or similar)

Answer (score 4):

There's an API call for this:

[size](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.

```
hmap.size();
```

As noted you're just overwriting the key/value pair with a new value.

Comment: gr8 i didnt knew that. Thanks for nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question has asked about having multiple keys in HashMap which is not possible.

If you pass null again and again the old value is replaced only.

Refer:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putForNullKey%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

HashMap allows multiple null values but only one null key.
If you write multiple null keys like below, then null will be overrides and you'll get the final overridden result. i.e "world"

```
  Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
  valueMap.put(null, "hello");
  valueMap.put(null, "world");

  System.out.println(valueMap.get(null));
```

Output:

```
"world"
```